# Issue in deleting the textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have two buttons for adding and deleting the textfields. Adding works fine but when I click on delete it deletes only the last added textfield. Here are my two methods:

```
-(void)addTextField {
    keyTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yAxisDistance, 150, 30)];
    keyTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    keyTextField.placeholder = @"Key Value";
    keyTextField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:keyTextField];

    valueTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, yAxisDistance, 150, 30)];
    valueTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    valueTextField.placeholder = @"Value";
    valueTextField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:valueTextField];
    yAxisDistance = yAxisDistance+35;
}

-(void)deleteTextField {
    [keyTextField removeFromSuperview];
    [valueTextField removeFromSuperview];
    yAxisDistance = yAxisDistance-35;
}
```

I know it's an small issue but I am very new to this field so kindly help.

Comment: You forgot to say what you want to achieve ? What is *deleteTextField* supposed to do ?

Comment: Set tag of every UITextField and remove using tag.

Comment: Or if you have made the textfields as properties in your interface, access them using self.

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda can you elaborate with an example bro. i will be able to understand more than. i am very new to iOS.

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda suppose i have clicked on add button 3 times, it will create 3 textfields but when i click on delete button it deletes only the last added textfield. and if i click again on delete it is not deleting any other textfield.i want that if i click on delete button 3 times it should delete 3 textfields.

Comment: If you click add button 3 times than every time set tag of UITextField  by yourextField.tag method. and Increament tag value by 1 every time you create new textFields

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre he want to create multiple textField and delete textField from already added textFields

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda tried your code but still its not working.

Comment: @Newbee see my updated code. It solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you store the last textField in your variables keyTextField and valueTextField. So when you call your deleteTextField the last both will be deleted. you must track which textFileds you want exactly to delete.

for example you could give all your textFields a tag number when you create them:
first create an int as counter:

```
@implementation YourClass {
    int tagcounter;
}
```

in init method set your counter:

```
tagcounter = 0;
```

in your addTextField:

```
keyTextField.tag = tagcounter++;
valueTextField.tag = tagcounter++;
```

when the delete button is tapped, you must know the textfield tags and pass them to your deleteTextField method. There you could do something like:

```
-(void)deleteTextFieldWithTag:(int)tagnumber {
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        if (view.tag == tagnumber || view.tag == tagnumber+1) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: tried this but still its deleting only the last added textfield.

Comment: you must give all textfield different tags, not each pair 1 and 2., so that you have pairs like 1,2 and 3,4 and 5,6 and so on...

Comment: little bit of changes but it worked and i understood also. thank you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for remove specific textfield from UIView. But First you have to set tag of every UITextField in view when you create or add it in view.

```
for ( UITextField* textField in view.subviews ) 
{
    if(textField.tag== 1)
    {
          [textField removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: If we have instance declaration of UITextField then what is need of checking here with tag value ?

Comment: @Newbee my code is working for me... ok i'm sending you my sample code  which is working for me. Compare your code with it. The download link is: http://ge.tt/4AN5tM31/v/0?c

Comment: @Newbee you have to download PradhyumanDemo.zip file for your code

Comment: yes it was helpful to understand few things about textfields.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that time I was not understand your problem...

I done with this: 
Declare one

> NSMutableArray *allTextfieldArray;

and initialise in

> viewdidload

method.. 
now do:

```
-(void)addTextField {
    keyTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yAxisDistance, 150, 30)];
    keyTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    keyTextField.placeholder = @"Key Value";
    keyTextField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:keyTextField];

    valueTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, yAxisDistance, 150, 30)];
    valueTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    valueTextField.placeholder = @"Value";
    valueTextField.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:valueTextField];

    yAxisDistance = yAxisDistance+35;

    [allTextfieldArray addObject:keyTextField];
    [allTextfieldArray addObject:valueTextField];

}


if ([allTextfieldArray count]>0) {
    UITextField *txtField =     [allTextfieldArray lastObject];
    [allTextfieldArray removeLastObject];

    [txtField removeFromSuperview];
    txtField = nil;


    UITextField *txtField2 =      [allTextfieldArray lastObject];
    [allTextfieldArray removeLastObject];

    [txtField2 removeFromSuperview];
    txtField2 = nil;

    yAxisDistance = yAxisDistance-35;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with the outlet. Can you check the following:

1. Open the outlets that are connected to the textifeld in the IB. There should be gray dots inside circles on the left side of the editor. Are they seem correct for both text fields?
2. Setup a breakpoint inside `deleteTextField` method and check the two textfields. Verify that both properties are not nil.

PS: You don't need to add tags to your view, using properties is perfectly fine and even better in my opinion. The reason for your problem is something else. Also, you do not need to `removeFromSuperview`, you can also `setHidden:YES.`